# Finding integer part of $(3+\sqrt{3})^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I need to find the integer part of $(3+\sqrt{3})^4$, ie the floor of it and I am unable to proceed.

I can find integer part of $(2+\sqrt{3})^4$ using the binomial theorem as $2-\sqrt{3}<1$.

Please give a hint. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try expanding $(3+\sqrt{3})^4$?

Comment: Observe that $\sqrt{a^2 + r}$, where $a^2 < a^2 + r < (a+1)^2$, satisfies $a < \sqrt{a^2 + r} < a +1$ - so it's clear that the integer part of $\sqrt{a^2 + r}$ will be $a$.

Comment: @fractal1729 Sorry and thanks! never bother me i am an idiot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used my recollection that $\sqrt3=1.732\dots$

Note that $\left(3-\sqrt3\right)^4\doteq1.268^4\in(2,3)$ since $1.2^4=2.0736$ and $1.3^4=2.8561$.

$$
a_n=\left(3+\sqrt3\right)^n+\left(3-\sqrt3\right)^n
$$
satisfies $a_n=6a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2}$ and starts out $2,6,24,108,\color{#C00}{504},\dots$

Thus, $\left\lfloor\left(3+\sqrt3\right)^4\right\rfloor=501$.

Comment: I think its not possible without some approximation, I too was getting a result as $504-t$ where $t \in (0,10)$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**
$$
\left(3+\sqrt3\right)^2 = 3^2 + 3 + 6\sqrt3 = 6\left(2+ \sqrt3\right)
$$
and
$$
\left(3+\sqrt3\right)^4 = \left(\left(3+\sqrt3\right)^2\right)^2
$$

Comment: How do we use $2-\sqrt{3}<1$ ?

Comment: Simple and sweet. I understand it!

Comment: Wait I didn't quite get the answer! We have this equal to $36(2+\sqrt{3})^2$. Letting $(2+\sqrt{3})^2 = x$, we have now $36(x) = 36(\lfloor x\rfloor + (x-\lfloor x\rfloor))$. Now what do we do?

Comment: I would then say $36(2+\sqrt 3)^2=36(7+4\sqrt 3)=36\cdot 7+ 144\sqrt 3$ and just multiply $144 \cdot 1.732$ by hand.  If it came out too close to an integer I would be in trouble, but it doesn't here.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to look at $f(n) = (3+\sqrt{3})^n + (3-\sqrt{3})^n$.  It's easy to see that $f(4) = 504$.  You have

$$(3 + \sqrt{3})^4 = 3^4 + 4 \cdot 3^3 \cdot \sqrt{3} + 6 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3 + 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 (\sqrt{3}) + 9 = 252 + 144 \sqrt{3}$$

and when you expand out $(3-\sqrt{3})^4$ similarly the terms with $\sqrt{3}$ come out negated, so you get $(3 - \sqrt{3})^4 = 252 - 144 \sqrt{3}$.

Now what else can you say about $(3-\sqrt{3})^4$?  In particular, can you find its integer part? (This might require a bit of hand calculation.)

Comment: robjohn's solution fills in some of the details of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have restrictions on the methods to use the simplest one is to use your calculator (!).
$$\lfloor (3+\sqrt3)^4\rfloor \approx\lfloor 501.415\rfloor = 501.$$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention but calculators were not allowed!